# Combine: update values each other

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

The example code here is very simple. Sliders update double values but not the other way around. Using Combine how to update two or more sliders on each other?

```swift
struct Centimeters {
    var value: Double
    
    func updateInches() -> Double {
        return value / 2.54
    }
}

struct Inches {
    var value: Double
    
    func updateCentimeters() -> Double {
        return value * 2.54
    }
}

class SizeValueModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var centimeters: Centimeters
    @Published var inches: Inches
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        self.centimeters = Centimeters(value: 1.0)
        self.inches = Inches(value: 0.393701)
        
        $centimeters.sink {
            self.inches.value = $0.updateInches()
        }.store(in: &cancellables)
        
//        $inches.sink {
//            self.centimeters.value = $0.updateCentimeters()
//        }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = SizeValueModel()
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $model.centimeters.value, in: 0...100, label: {
            Text("\(model.centimeters.value)")
        })
        Slider(value: $model.inches.value, in: 0...39.3701, label: {
            Text("\(model.inches.value)")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe relevant https://forums.swift.org/t/is-this-a-bug-in-published/31292

Comment: What happens if you uncomment the second piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see when you attempt to add your currently-commented second `sink`, you'll end up with a circular dependency between the inches and centimeters. Instead, I'd suggest you store *one* value and use a custom binding for the other:

```
struct Centimeters {
    var value: Double
}

class SizeValueModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var centimeters: Centimeters
    
    var inchesBinding : Binding<Double> {
        .init {
            self.centimeters.value / 2.54
        } set: {
            self.centimeters.value = $0 * 2.54
        }

    }
    
    init() {
        self.centimeters = Centimeters(value: 1.0)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = SizeValueModel()
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $model.centimeters.value, in: 0...100, label: {
            Text("\(model.centimeters.value)")
        })
        Slider(value: model.inchesBinding, in: 0...39.3701, label: {
            Text("\(model.inchesBinding.wrappedValue)")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the circular dependency was the problem. With Binding<Double> is an easy solution that avoid using Combine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is that you create an infinite loop since you're observing two values that change each other.

1. Inches change -> Centimeters gets updated
2. Centimeters change -> Inches gets updated
3. Inches change -> Centimeters gets updated
4. Centimeters change -> Inches gets updated
5. ... and so on

@jnpdx answer is the right answer imho (it allows you to have a single source of truth)

Alternatively (maybe can be useful for other use cases), you could check whether values actually change so that you could avoid to trigger a useless update.

First make your structs conforming to `Equatable`

```swift
struct Centimeters: Equatable {
    // ...
}

struct Inches: Equatable {
    // ...
}
```

Then, in your view model apply a modifier to the publisher to avoid triggering the event if value is not actually changed.

```swift
$centimeters
    .removeDuplicates()
    .sink {
        self.inches.value = $0.updateInches()
    }.store(in: &cancellables)
$inches
    .removeDuplicates()
    .sink {
        self.centimeters.value = $0.updateCentimeters()
    }.store(in: &cancellables)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Yes, as you wrote the @jnpdx answer, with a single source of truth, avoid using Combine.